# How to Put a Subtitle Under Bootstrap Navbar Brand Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navigation bar. Which includes logo, brand heading and a subtitle. I want to the subtitle under the brand heading but it is going under the logo. I have also tried the flex property but I think I messed something with that so even that did not worked. I am pretty novice to all this so I hope I'll be pardoned for any silly mistakes.

```css
.navbar-custom {
 margin-bottom:0;
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
}
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item {
 font-size:13px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform:none;
 letter-spacing:1px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
 outline:0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
 padding:4px 6px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
 outline:0;
  
  .navbar-brand small {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/75" height="75" class="d-inline-block" alt="">  <span>Lorem Logo <br><small>Subtitle</small></span></a>
            <button class="navbar-light navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsDefault" aria-controls="navbarsDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-custom navbar-nav ml-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-item.html">Project</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="page.html">Page Layout</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="post.html">Post Layout</a>
                        
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Hire me</a>
                    </li>

                    

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your codepen link is not working, but you should put the code in your question in the first place, not a codepen link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the `d-flex` class to `.navbar-brand` and give a `padding-left` or `margin-left` to the `<span>` that contains your logo and sub-title.

I gave that span the class `ml-3` to give it a `margin-left` of 1em in this example.

```css
.navbar-custom {
 margin-bottom:0;
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
}
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item {
 font-size:13px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform:none;
 letter-spacing:1px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
 outline:0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
 padding:4px 6px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
 outline:0;
  
  .navbar-brand small {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-flex" href="index.html">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/75" height="75" class="d-inline-block" alt="">      <span class="ml-3">Lorem Logo <br><small>Subtitle</small></span></a>
            <button class="navbar-light navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsDefault" aria-controls="navbarsDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-custom navbar-nav ml-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio-item.html">Project</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="page.html">Page Layout</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="post.html">Post Layout</a>
                        
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Hire me</a>
                    </li>

                    

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. You saved my life. I was trying to find a solution since last day. And only two changes made that work. Thank you a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)